# how could mongodb use query condition, index, sort at the same time?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing, find

My company project use mongodb as database.
Current data structure is like below: (for table user)

```
{
  username:xxx,
  password:xxx,
  firstname:xxx,
  lastname:xxx,
  age:xxx,
  created_at:xxx,
  updated_at:xxx
}
```

Because this data will be supported by any query condition and sort condtion (more than one). 
You know mongodb has to use combine field index at first, but I can't use index for every combination of fields.

So i try to change data structure like below:

```
{
  data:[{key:username,value:xxx},
        {key:password,value:xxx},
        ....],
  username:xxx,
  password:xxx,
  firstname:xxx,
  lastname:xxx,
  age:xxx,
  created_at:xxx,
  updated_at:xxx
}
```

If I still use db.collection.find() function ,i can't use sort. Cause I can't accomplish that when data.key = username, sort data.value

If I use db.coolection.aggregate() function, i can't support sort for more than one field.

So how can I achieve my goal?

Is there any other data structure design?
Or is there any options I can do for find or aggregate function?

Comment: Why do you say you cannot sort by multiple fields when using aggregation?

Comment: > Because this data will be supported by any query condition and sort condtion (more than one). You know mongodb has to use combine field index at first, but I can't use index for every combination of fields.

Comment: sorry, hit enter too quick.
I'm really unclear as to what the problem is. Are you saying that you can't search those documents effectively because you can't create enough compound indices? I don't see why it would be a problem to simply create a normal index on each of those fields. Storing arrays of key-value pairs is an anti-pattern, and best avoided. If you can restate what the problem is it would be helpful.

Comment: To Asya: My project mongodb version is 2.4. I use aggregate() like this: ` User.aggregate([
            { $match: {"$and":matchObj1}},
            { $unwind: '$data'},
            { $match: {"$and":matchSort}},
            { $sort: {
                'data.value': -1
            }}]); `
you know sort will depend on $unwind: '$data'}. if i need to sort by multiple fields, what should i do?

Comment: To allTwentyQuestions: i just know mongodb has Index Intersection in version 2.6. but my project mongodb version is 2.4. I know this question is a little complex. I can create enough compound indices, but i think it's a litter stupid, if i add a new field to table, i have to create more and more compound indices. so i decide to change data structure for create index once in data.key and data.value. but the problem is i cannot sort by multiple fields in aggregate().